# MySQL REPEATABLE-READ Workbench transaction level not set

Tags: mysql, innodb, workbench, transaction-isolation, read-committed

We have set the following in the my.ini file

[mysqld]
transaction-isolation = READ-COMMITTED

We assume this setting will be the default for all user sessions.

When logging in using PHPMyAdmin the tx_isolation is set correctly and works as expected. However, when connecting to the server using MySQL Workbench 6.0 an examination of the variables shows that the tx_isolation level is set to REPEATABLE-READ. The effects of this isolation level are also as expected.

We want to set the transaction-isolation level to READ-COMMITTED globally, preferably at DB startup.

We have restarted the server (V 5.5.25a) and obviously workbench. Storage engine is INNODB.

Comment: There's a [verified bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69800) on this. No idea what the status of it though. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25268782/mysql-workbench-and-default-session-isolation-level, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26208007/mysql-workbench-session-does-not-see-updates-to-the-database

Answer (score 0):

```
SET GLOBAL TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-transaction.html

Comment: Yes, we did that. Same result. We want it set for all users all the time (regardless of if they have the privilege to SET GLOBAL). Unfortunately that's not happening. I have read the documentation.